# Using attributes as text in angular component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this little component:

```
.component('obsbox', {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'app/components/interactions/html/interactions.obsBox.partial.html',
        controller: 'InteractionsController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindings: {}
    });
```

All it does it produce a box with some text in it. Nothing spectacular. What I'd like to do is pass a few attributes into the tag and then display those attributes when it resolves.

```
<obsbox title1="Positive" title2="Experience" score="1"></obsbox>
```

That should give me a box with "1" in at the top and "Positive Experience" in the bottom. I haven't been able to find anything on SO or anywhere else that explains how I would do that in a way I can understand.

There's nothing in my controller or anywhere else that would be helpful to show you. My controllers are literally doing nothing at the moment.

Any advice?

Edit:
here's the html for the component:

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="start center" flex="11">
    <div layout="column" layout-align="center center" flex="100">
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex="100">
            1
        </div>
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex="100">
            <div layout="column" layout-align="center center" flex="100" style="font-size: x-small">
                <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex="100">
                    POSITIVE
                </div>
                <div layout="row" layout-align="center center" flex="100">
                    ATTITUDE
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my ideal world "1", "Positive", and "Attitude" would come from from attributes on the obsbox tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen the example at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component ?

You should fill your bindings like this:

```
bindings: {
title1:"@",
title2="@",
score="@"
}
```

`@` denotes text binding. See the link above for more binding options.

You can then use `{{ $ctrl.title1 }}` and the other bindings in the template.

For an example, see https://plnkr.co/edit/Gv3TofiO0QyjAOkODjPv?p=info

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. At the moment I just want simple strings in those places, and this solution worked perfectly for that. At some point I'm going to want to change those attributes based on scoring and other factors, but I have an idea on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can load it into scope using a [`link` function](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) in your directive:

```
.component('obsbox', {
    // the other directive parameters

    link: (scope, element, attributes, controller) => {
        controller.title1 = attributes.title1;
        controller.title2 = attributes.title2;
    }
});
```

The `link` function is executed once, upon directive compilation.

If you need to update the value, you need to add a watch to that attribute. Angular provides a way to observe attributes with the `$observe` function:

```
// in the link function body
attributes.$observe('title1', newValue => {
    controller.title1 = newValue;
});
```

Note that this way, it's using plain strings, not Angular expressions. This means that if you want to have an expression, you would need the `$parse` service in the directive, or use interpolation at usage site.

Comment: Don't do this. Use bindings instead